# UITextField clearButton keeps returning wrong image

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, xcode5, uitextfield

I am trying to access the UIImage of the UITextField. But it keeps returning the magnifying glass instead of the x mark. What am I doing wrong?

```
UIButton *clearButton = [searchField valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];
UIImage *clearImage = clearButton.imageView.image;//[clearButton imageForState:UIControlState];
```

I know the x mark is there because it always shows up when I start typing in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 64)];
self.tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; //maybe you need do this    

UIButton *clearButton = [self.tf valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];
UIImage *clearImage = clearButton.imageView.image;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:clearImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out my code was correct. There was a typo somewhere else in the program. But yours works too.